# sqlmap verbose level

Tags: sqlmap

pretty much on every resource I go, it says the sqlmap's verbose value `-v` can be from 1 to 6 and default is 1, I try to look anywhere to see the difference between those values, but I can not find any specific information,

Can anyone tell me difference it makes for values 1 to 6 ?

[this link](https://cdn.comparitech.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/sqlmap-Cheat-Sheet.webp) contains a cheatsheet for sqlmap

Answer (score 1):

The sqlmap codebase seems to have a number of cases where the handling of higher verbosity numbers are hardcoded in different ways, f.ex handling for connections: https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/blob/fdbc323aa61750eb4f0259fdb3fffebde5ddb01b/lib/request/connect.py#L762

```
            if conf.verbose <= 5:
                responseMsg += getUnicode(logHeaders)
            elif conf.verbose > 5:
                responseMsg += "%s\r\n\r\n%s" % (logHeaders, (page or "")[:MAX_CONNECTION_READ_SIZE])
```

Most of the conditions only seem to check if the value is 1 or 2 so the differences may be quite subtle or only present under certain conditions. You can look at other verbosity conditions by searching the sqlmap codebase:
https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/search?p=2&q=verbose